# while using npm start it shows failed to compile can't resolve

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules

Failed to compile
./node_modules/jest-serializer/build/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'v8' in 'C:\Users\Desktop\reactapp\react-project\node_modules\jest-serializer\build'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Comment: Have you installed all of the dependencies? `npm install`?

Comment: yes i install all the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps :

1.Remove package-lock.json file.

2.Run npm install command.

3.Try to execute npm start again.